# How to embed file to word docx?

Tags: c#, embed, docx

I'm trying to insert a file programmatically (*.zip for example) into an existing docx file.

I looked at the docx open library but it doesn't have the function there.

Also tried using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word. I created a word document with a table, and I'm trying to insert a file into a cell inside the table.

```
Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
wordApp.Visible = false;

Word.Document doc = new Word.Document();
doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\test.docx");
doc.Tables[1].Rows[2].Cells[1].Range.InsertFile((Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\tttt.zip"));
```

but it caused an error:

> "The file appears to be corrupted"

Can anyone have experience and help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error...
The function "Range.InsertFile" doesn't actually inserts a file, it reads and appends the text into the Range.

The solution was simple - Copy paste...

```
using System.Collections.Specialized;
...
...
//Copy the Filename to Clipboard (setFile function uses StringCollection)
StringCollection collection = new StringCollection();
collection.Add(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\MyFile.zip");
Clipboard.SetFileDropList(collection);

//Paste into the selected Range.
range.Paste();
```

*There is also function "PasteSpecial" which didn't work (Only specific data types are supported).

Comment: While this might work, it does modify the clipboard of the unsuspecting user. It is better to use "InlineShapes.AddOLEObject"